# STL loaded in three.js in wrong orientation

Tags: three.js

In three.js I loaded STL model and it is loaded fine.
But actually model orientation is quite different than it is loaded. When I load it in other CAD viewers and software like Blender it is oriented along z-direction but in three.js it is oriented along x-direction. Actually my model is a pipe and is oriented along z-direction, i don't know why three.js is loading it in x-direction?

Comment: Different software uses different coordinate system. Get used to that ;) If there is an option to export the model in another coordinate system, do so. Otherwise, just rotate it in three.js during the loader callback i would suggest :)

Comment: How would I know what is the actual orientation of the model to rotate it during loader callback. I have different models and I don't even know what is their orientation prior to loading.

Comment: Well, i think there are only 2 Possibilities: 1) 2 axes are interchanged, for example x- and z-axis (as you described). This would be the case if three.js uses another coordinate system (or whatever the case is) as the program you are exporting from, then the rotation is always the same. 2) If you have many models that are arbitrarily rotated in their original software, you will never know how to rotate them correctly and stl-file format does not give you any information about the original coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
mesh.rotation.set(0, 0,  - Math.PI / 2);
```

just before you add your model to the scene.